# how can i resolve error while installing new react app project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I type command 'npx create-react-app my-app' on terminal the following error occurs:_
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React>npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
And almost similar error occur when I type 'npm install':_
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-26T08_52_13_498Z-debug-0.log
I have installed nodejs:
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React>node
Welcome to Node.js v18.17.0.
Type ".help" for more information.

How to resolve this error?

When I type command 'npx create-react-app my-app' or 'npm install' on terminal error occurs
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\React>npx create-react-app my-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

Answer (score -1):

The error message you provided indicates that there is an issue with the npm package manager, specifically related to a missing file or directory. This error often occurs due to npm configuration problems or corrupted npm cache. To fix this issue, you can try the following steps:

**Clear npm cache:**
Sometimes, clearing the npm cache can resolve the problem. Open your terminal or command prompt and run the following command:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

**Update npm:**
Ensure that you have the latest version of npm installed. Run the following command to update npm:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

**Verify npm configuration:**
Check your npm configuration to ensure it points to the correct directories. Run the following commands to verify:

```
npm config get prefix
npm config get cache
```

Make sure the output paths are valid and exist on your system. If they are not correct, you can set them using the following commands (replace the paths with appropriate ones):

```
npm config set prefix /path/to/your/npm/prefix
npm config set cache /path/to/your/npm/cache
```

If the problem persists, there might be other issues with your system's configuration or npm installation.